NextJS 15 and react-slick: problem with importing react-slick styles
i'm using NextJS 15 and tried react-slick out with app router. I got into an issue with this combiniation. So my problem is here that i normaly loaded, as i saw it everywhere else, the styles needed for react-slick like this on my layout.tsx page:
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import localFont from "next/font/local";
import "./globals.scss";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";

const geistSans = localFont({
  src: "./fonts/GeistVF.woff",
  variable: "--font-geist-sans",
  display: "swap", // Optional für bessere Ladezeiten
});

const geistMono = localFont({
  src: "./fonts/GeistMonoVF.woff",
  variable: "--font-geist-mono",
  display: "swap", // Optional für bessere Ladezeiten
});

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Website",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={`antialiased`}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}

my next.config.ts (also tried it without and with transpilePackages)
import type { NextConfig } from "next";

const nextConfig: NextConfig = {
  transpilePackages: ["react-slick", "slick-carousel"],
  /* config options here */
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: "http",
        hostname: "somedomain.com",
        port: "",
      },
    ],
  },
};

export default nextConfig;

and my issue when i build it with Docker and start it on production is that it says:
Failed to compile
./node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)

@charset 'UTF-8';
| /* Slider */
| .slick-loading .slick-list


after a long night i came to the solution that i was missing sass and the sass emededded packages and also the configuration on my next.config.ts:
  sassOptions: {
    ...sassOptions,
    implementation: "sass-embedded",
  },

